# How replace a String with another String in a Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've the following Data Frame.

```
data = pd.read_csv("Example.csv")
data["Column1"]

     Column0   Column1

0      a       Gold 
1      b       Silver  
2      b       Silver (Running)
3      c       Bronze (800m)
4      c       Bronze 
5      a       2x Gold (500m)
6      a       Really Successful, 2x WM Gold (500m)
```

My Goal is to replace some of the Strings with only the Medals.

```
data = pd.read_csv("Example.csv")
data["Column1"]

     Column0     Column1

0      a         Gold
1      b         Silver
2      b         Silver
3      c         Bronze
4      c         Bronze
5      a         Gold
6      a         Gold
7      a         Gold
8      a         Gold
```

I've already tried the `replace()` method. But it doesnt work.
Like this :

```
data[Column1] = data.replace({"Column1": "Silver"}, "Silver)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `str.extract`

```py
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(Gold|Silver|Bronze)')
```

```
print(df)

  Column0 Column1
0       a    Gold
1       b  Silver
2       b  Silver
3       c  Bronze
4       c  Bronze
5       a    Gold
6       a    Gold
```

To ignore case, you can use `flags` argument

```py
import re

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(gold|silver|bronze)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
data[Column1] = data.replace({'Silver (Running)':'Silver'})
data[Column1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define clearly the problem that you want to solve
Your problem here is not a use case for `replace`, what you want to do is to keep only the medal in the column "Column1", and not to replace the whole string.
You might solve this problem as follows
*Creation of the data frame*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Column0": ["a","b","b","c","c","a","a",], "Column1":[
    "Gold ",
    "Silver  ",
    "Silver (Running)",
    "Bronze (800m)",
    "Bronze ",
    "2x Gold (500m)",
    "Really Successful, 2x WM Gold (500m)",
]})
```

You can use apply on the column `Column1` using the following function

```
def replace_string_by_medal(string):
    for medal in ["Gold","Silver","Bronze"]:
        if medal in string:
            return medal

df.Column1.apply(replace_string_by_medal)
```

This will return a column that has what you want and you can replace the column `Column1` with the new value

```
df.loc["Column1"] = df.Column1.apply(replace_string_by_medal)

df
```

```
    Column0 Column1
0   a       Gold
1   b       Silver
2   b       Silver
3   c       Bronze
4   c       Bronze
5   a       Gold
6   a       Gold
```

Comment: `apply` is not efficient for this operation, futhermore, using an additional for loop in your function makes it quadratic, you should not have to search as many times as there are possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

As you have a defined list of possibilities, the easiest is to use `str.extract`:

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(Gold|Silver|Bronze)')
```

output:

```
  Column0 Column1
0       a    Gold
1       b  Silver
2       b  Silver
3       c  Bronze
4       c  Bronze
5       a    Gold
6       a    Gold
```